# unable to create window with OpenGL 3.3 context macOS with GLFW installed through brew

Tags: c, haskell, opengl, glfw

I am unable to create GLFW windows with versions past 2.1 after install glfw through brew using the command `brew install glfw`.

basically my problem is that this code works:

```hs
import qualified Graphics.UI.GLFW as GLFW

configAndCreateWindow :: IO (Maybe GLFW.Window)
configAndCreateWindow = do              
    GLFW.windowHint (GLFW.WindowHint'ContextVersionMajor 2)
    GLFW.windowHint (GLFW.WindowHint'ContextVersionMinor 1)
    GLFW.createWindow 100 100 "test" Nothing Nothing

main :: IO ()
main = do
    GLFW.init
    maybeWindow <- configAndCreateWindow
    case maybeWindow of
        Nothing -> putStrLn "Failure :("
        Just _ -> putStrLn "Success!"
```

but if I change

```hs
GLFW.windowHint (GLFW.WindowHint'ContextVersionMajor 2)
GLFW.windowHint (GLFW.WindowHint'ContextVersionMinor 1)
```

to

```hs
GLFW.windowHint (GLFW.WindowHint'ContextVersionMajor 3)
GLFW.windowHint (GLFW.WindowHint'ContextVersionMinor 3)
```

it breaks.

Just to make sure it didn't have to do with GLFW-b I also wrote a c program:

```c
#define GLFW_INCLUDE_GL_3
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
    glfwInit();

    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);

    GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(800, 600, "GLFW test", NULL, NULL);
    if (window == NULL) {
        printf("Success!");
    } else {
        printf("Failure :(");
    }
}
```

and if I change context version number it works just like with the Haskell example.

Comment: Does de C version works for OGL3.3? You can also try adding `glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);`

Comment: no, it doesn't. Also I've tried adding and removing `glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);` and the Haskell equivalent from their respective programs with no success

Comment: Old driver may accept only OGL **3.2** version, and not 3.3 one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When requesting an OpenGL context on MacOS, two additional flags have to be set:

```
glfwWindowHint (GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);
glfwWindowHint (GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
```

Comment: I frequently  see recomending `GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT` on OSX. But the [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsopenglpixelformat/1436146-opengl_profiles) and [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsopenglpixelformat/1436213-opengl_pixel_format_attributes) have not this context flag

Comment: @Ripi2: As far as I know, macOS core profiles are always forward compatible (they don't implemented non forward compatible profiles). But I have never check it in detail. The glfw doc states: "The OS only supports forward-compatible core profile contexts for OpenGL versions 3.2 and later.  Before creating an OpenGL context of version 3.2 or later you must set the GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT" (Source: [glfw3.h:2583](https://github.com/glfw/glfw/blob/a4d910b4a72f3a85d7be42ea2f91162cdfd28375/include/GLFW/glfw3.h))